# smart groups showing on tab

Tags: groups, smartgroups

CiviCRM 4.5.8(really any version, I think) and WP 4.2.4.

In a contact record the Groups tab will show a number.  This is the number of the "Regular Groups".  Is it possible to also show/combine the Smart Groups number on the Groups tab as well?

Answer (score 2):

Gary,

the quick answer is no ....the way CiviCRM stores the groups for a contacts is different than the way CiviCRM determines which smart groups a contact is in. There is one group table that references which contact is in which group.  This table does not contain smart group references.

See the CiviCRM group architecture [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+data+architecture)

Comment: To add to Paul's answer - it's not impossible to count smart groups, but it would be very bad for performance.

Comment: Yeah... makes sense... I guess a process or data field could be stored to count the smart groups during the Scheduled Job "Rebuild Smart Group Cache".   I don't know Civi and it's data well enough yet... not a programmer but would be really nice to have a Smart Group count or at least some type of indicator instead of absolutely nothing!  Thoughts?

Comment: Just curious as to whether anything has changed on this front in the past 4 years? My organization would find it very helpful to see Smart Groups counted in the Groups tab for each contact. They save staff a lot of data management time, so we use very few non-Smart Groups. Yet every time a user pulls up an individual's contact record, they feel compelled to check the Groups tab to make sure the right Smart Groups are there. This constant second-guessing of the system erodes much of the time saved by setting up the Smart Groups.